# Finding out the time taken to execute a function

Tags: .net, visual-c++

I wrote a function to match fingerprint templates using VC++.NET.

Now I want to know the time it takes to execute the function.

I tried surrounding the function call statement with [clock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30(VS.71).aspx) ( Standard C Library ) and computing the difference in the values returned. For some reason it always returns zero. Am I missing something here or are there alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just used the System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch? I'm assuming its both the same in VC++.NET and C#.NET.

If you can then you just need VC++ equivalent of :

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew()
Func();
sw.Stop();
```

Might want to check out [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx)

Comment: I think the library function that I call for actually matching the templates has a very sophisticated and efficient implementation. It just takes few hundred nanoseconds to complete. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

clock_t start , end ;

start = clock();

funct();

end = clock();

double exe_time =  (end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; // in second